# Network while Connecting to AWS Linux Instance from Windows Using PuTTY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to a AWS linux instance from windows using Putty using the instructions @ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html but running into error shown in screen shot [Network error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mYX6.png) ,can anyone provide assistance on how to debug this and fix it?

[image: Securitygroups screenshot]

Comment: Please let me know if any additional info is missing on this,I really need support on this

Comment: The extra info you'll need to provide is about how you have your instance configured. The most likely issue is that you either haven't added a public IP, or that you have not added a security group that has your IP address configured to be allowed in on port 22 (which is what you need to connect with SSH from PuTTY).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment Sean,I configured in the exact same way as mentioned in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNr7YqjjzOY ,if you have any specific questions on configuration please let me know,i attached a screen shot of my security group,do you see anything wrong? are you saying I need add my windows IP adress to the security group on port 22?

Comment: Your security group looks OK (although I would recommend rather using your computers IP/32 rather than 0.0.0.0/0 for the port 22 entry because that allows access from anywhere), it sounds like you may need to try changing your keep alive - see this answer
http://superuser.com/questions/294824/putty-network-error-software-caused-connection-abort

Comment: that didnt work either,I also tried all the steps again @http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout and created a newinstance but I see the same error,I have no clue what could be wrong

Comment: Something you could try is using Bitvise (https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client) instead of PuTTY. I actually prefer it to PuTTY - I don't really think it will solve the problem you're having, which seems to be a networking one, but it's probably worth a try. Do you have a local firewall that might be blocking your connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your EC2 instance is running

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration of iptables in your server, and ensure there's a Public ip or Elastic IP attached on your instance,after that, verify if your route-table has 0.0.0.0/0 item,and the corresponding next-hop is an IGW. Networking problems are always the most common problems in this situation.